# Xcode: Can't create new swift files

Tags: swift, xcode6

The option to create new Swift Files seems to have disappeared from my xcode.

Any Ideas how to get it back?

[image: latest xcode version]

[image: No Option for Swift Files]

Comment: You have to upgrade your Xcode to at least 6.1.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just saw that it was solved by resetting Xcode to defaults by typing the following into Terminal

```
defaults delete com.apple.dt.Xcode
```

Back to normal!